# Given triangle ABC with $\alpha=2\beta$ and $b, c, a$ is forming an arithmetic sequence. Find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Given $\triangle ABC$ with $\alpha=2\beta$ and $b, c, a$ is forming an arithmetic sequence ($b$ is the $1$'st term, and $a$ is the last term), find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

My attempts so far: 
Let $c=b+k$ and $a=b+2k$. Then, from $\alpha=2\beta$, I got $\gamma = 180^\circ - 3\beta$.

With the Law of Sines , I can write
$$\dfrac{b}{\sin \beta}=\dfrac{b+k}{\sin 3\beta}=\frac{b+2k}{\text{sin } 2\beta}$$

From $\dfrac{b}{\sin\beta}=\dfrac{b+k}{\sin 3\beta}$, it gives $\cos 2\beta = \dfrac{k}{2b}$.

From $\dfrac{b}{\sin \beta}=\dfrac{b+2k}{\sin 2\beta}$, it gives $\cos \beta = \dfrac{b+2k}{2b}$.

After this, I don't know what should I do. Is there any other theorem that can be used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $b,c,a$ forming an arithmetic sequence,
$$c-b=a-c$$ $$2c=a+b$$ Applying sine rule, $$2\sin C=\sin A+\sin B$$
Using the given data $A=2B$, we can rewrite the above as, $$2\sin 3B=\sin2B+\sin B$$ $$\require{cancel}2\cdot \cancel{2\sin\frac{3B}{2}}\cos\frac{3B}2=\cancel{2\sin\frac{3B}{2}}\cos\frac B2\qquad\small{(\because\sin\frac{3B}{2}\neq0})$$
Now letting $\cos\frac B2=x$, we get, $$2(4x^3-3x)=x$$ $$x^2=\frac78$$ Therefore, $$\cos B=2\cos^2\frac B2-1=\frac34$$ $$B=\cos^{-1}\frac34$$

So we have found $B$ alias $\beta$ which leads to find other angles as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Lemma:** Since $\angle A=2\angle B$, $$a^2=b(b+c)$$
**Proof:** [In a triangle $∠A=2∠B$ iff $a^2=b(b+c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557704/in-a-triangle-angle-a-2-angle-b-iff-a2-bbc)

Using the above result,
$$(c+k)^2=(c-k)(2c-k)\implies (c+k)^2=(c-k)^2+c(c-k)\implies 4ck=c(c-k) $$
$$\therefore\; c=5k$$
Hence, the sides of the triangle are $(6k,4k,5k)$ and you can apply the cosine rule to finish it off.
$$(4k)^2=(5k)^2+(6k)^2-2\cdot(5k)\cdot (6k)\cos \beta$$
$$\therefore\; \beta =\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can continue from where you left off. Using the fact that $\cos 2 \beta = 2 \cos^2 \beta - 1$:

$$2 \left( \frac{b+2k}{2b} \right)^2 - 1 = \frac{k}{2b}$$
$$2 (b + 2k)^2 - 4b^2 = 2bk$$
$$2b^2 + 8bk + 8k^2 - 4b^2 = 2bk$$
$$-2b^2 + 6bk + 8k^2 = 0$$
$$b^2 - 3bk - 4k^2 = 0$$
$$(b+k)(b-4k) = 0$$

but since $c = b + k \ne 0$, $b = 4k$ which gives side lengths $(4k, 5k, 6k)$ and has the same angles as $(4,5,6)$. Now the cosine rule $\cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$ and so on can be used to find angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.